# More efficient regex than "(cg[agct])|(ag[ag])"

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match any of:

```
cgt, cgc, cga, cgg, aga, agg
```

They're DNA codons. Is the regex I've given, `(cg[agct])|(ag[ag])`, as efficient as it could be? It somehow seems clunky, and I wonder if I could use the fact that there has to be a `g` as the second character.

Comment: This seems like a pretty good implementation to me. To rely on `g` as the second character would also require verifying c or a as the first to determine the last group. This seems easier as you have it.

Comment: As for pure performance changing `(...)` (catched group) into `(?:...)` (non-catched group) will slightly improve the speed by not having to catch the group. Other than that I don't see much room for improvements at first glance.

Comment: I think that what you have is perfect.

Comment: The only way to know "for certain" is to *run a performance test* and play around with different approaches. The results will depend a good bit upon regular expression engine used as far as how it's handled. It *might* be just as efficient to supply all the values as alternation and, I somehow doubt it will play a large role in the remainder of the code. (If it *does* matter, it might be "faster" to skip using a regular expression entirely.)

Comment: Also, if speed does matter, make sure to not ruin it with doing something silly: e.g. make sure to use a "compiled regular expression" if supported and avoid the use of `$&` if in Perl, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up the comments:

It appears that what you have is pretty good.

The one suggestion is to change the grouping into a non-capturing group (or remove them all together).

Something like this seems optimal:

```
cg[agct]|ag[ag]
```

If you had a set that was FAR more frequent than the others, you could *possibly* speed it up (slightly) by adding it literally to the alternation:

```
cgg|cg[act]|ag[ag]
```

---

Internally, most regex engines will turn small character classes like this into their own alternation. It may be fastest to expand out the alternation all the way, or in different groups, to see the performance impact.

I would suggest that you should profile all three of these approaches with your regex engine:

```
cg[agct]|ag[ag]

cga|cgc|cgg|cgt|aga|agg

[ac]g[agct](?<!agt|agc)
```

The last one is the closest to an answer to your question, since it leverages the fact that a "g" is required in the middle and used a "negative lookbehind" to eliminate the invalid sets.

One other thing to check would be if just finding all instances of `[ac]g[agct]` (including the undesired "agt" and "agc") and then filtering them in your language of choice would be fastest.

---

### EDIT, FOR SCIENCE!

Here is a chart of the various types of matches and failures, along with their number of steps required to reach a conclusion (match or no match).

```
     cg[agct]|ag[ag]   [ac]g[agct](?<!agt|agc)    cga|cgc|cgg|cgt|aga|agg
agg  4                 6                          10                     
agc  4                 8                          10                     

cga  3                 6                          3                      

axa  3                 2                          8                      
cxa  3                 2                          10                      

xxx  2                 1                          6
```

So, it appears that (as we guessed), the methods have entirely different properties.

My hunch about splitting everything into an alternation was wrong.  Don't use that.

Your hunch about utilizing the "g" in the middle is warranted, except that for partial matches (agg, for example) and full matches (cga, for example) take longer.  However, throwing away bad results is *slightly* faster with the negative lookbehind version.

So, to compensate for the worst case, (8 checks versus 3 = delta -5) we would have to see at least 5 failing character positions. (2 checks versus 3 = delta 1 or 1 check versus 2 = delta 1)

**I guess, then, that you should use the negative lookbehind version if you anticipate that you will fail a match at 5 positions for every match that you find.**

---

### EDIT 2, A SLIGHTLY BETTER VERSION

Looking at how exactly the regex is going to evaluate each match, we can craft a better version that will let about half of the matches "fast track", and will also reduce the number of characters checked when the match fails.

```
       [ca]g(?:[ag]|(?<!ag)[ct])
agg    4
agc    7

cga    4

axa    2
cxa    2

xxx    1
```

This reduces all of the positive matches times by one or two comparisons each.

**Based on this, I would recommend using `[ca]g(?:[ag]|(?<!ag)[ct])` if you expect to check 4 or more positions for each match.**

Comment: This is my favourite website. I don't mean Stack Overflow, I mean right here, [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513477/more-efficient-regex-than-cgagctagag).

Comment: @user1002973: Thanks!  However, I still recommend that you do some experimenting on your own, if this is "mission-critical".  I'm using the timing info that I get from RegexBuddy, which may not be the same as with your RegEx engine.